# Can you prove this property?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, contest-math

Let $T : [0, 1]^2 → [0, 1]$. Consider
the following properties:

$T_1 : T(x, 1) = x$

$T_2 : T(x, y) = T (y, x) $

$T_3 : T(x, T (y, z)) = T(T (x, y), z) $

$T_4 $: If  $x ≤ u  , y ≤ v \Rightarrow T(x, y) ≤ T(u, v) $

Function $T: [0, 1]^2 → [0, 1]$ that satisfies
$T_1 −T_4$ is T-norm .
For $T(x) = \begin{cases}min(x,y),&max(x,y)=1,\\0,&o.w.\end{cases}
$ conditions 1, 2 and 4 obviously.

Can you help me prove condition 3.

Comment: sorry, may be I did not understand well your question, Are you trying to show that the function   $T$ is a norm ?

Comment: Accordingly, you should show that $T$  is a norm, so you  have to show the  $T$ satisfies the [THREE  properties of a norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Metrics_on_multisets)

Comment: Duplicate of [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2043186/the-smallest-t-norm) from the week before (and you need to show what you've tried, not just ask others to do your homework for you).

Comment: Actually, the question is not about proving that $T$ is a norm and also not a duplicate of the question linked by @barakmanos. But still, the OP should some effort.

Comment: @barak manos you are very koni and khahar jende...

Comment: Sorry, my Klingon is a little rusty, can you translate?

Comment: can you sent for me email address please...

Answer (score 1):

To show your function satisfies condition 3, you just need to do some casework.

If $x=1$, then $T(x, T(y,z)) = T(1, T(y,z)) = T(y,z)$ and $T(T(x,y), z) = T(T(1, y), z) = T(y, z)$.

If $y=1$, then $T(x, T(y,z)) = T(x, T(1,z)) = T(x,z)$ and $T(T(x,y), z) = T(T(x,1), z) = T(x, z)$.

If $z=1$, then $T(x, T(y,z)) = T(x, T(y,1)) = T(x,y)$ and $T(T(x,y), z) = T(T(x,y), 1) = T(x,y)$.

If none of $x$, $y$, or $z$ are $1$, then $T(x, T(y,z)) = T(x, 0) = 0$ and $T(T(x,y), z) = T(0, z) = 0$.

(You can read more about $T$-norms here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-norm)

Comment: very good...But I was wrong in raising the question...My perspective was set...

Comment: $T(x) = \begin{cases}min(xوy),&x+y>1,\\0,&o.w.\end{cases}$

Comment: can you help me again....sorry......